# If I install the daily build of 20.04 will it update to the final release?

Tags: 20.04

I just installed today's daily build. I shouldn't need to reinstall the OS when it officially releases in a few weeks right?

Comment: it does, thank you!

Comment: Please note if you start using 20.04 before release, and you refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic where you'll notice only supported releases of Ubuntu and flavors are on-topic for this site. For 20.04 questions you'll need to use a development support site such as IRC (#ubuntu+1) or Ubuntu Forums, or wait until after release for this site (expected release date for Ubuntu 20.04 is April 23rd, 2020 when your question will be on-topic here).